# Why one T-SQL function get different performance running in same server, using same tables but call it from different databases instances

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the follow situation, I have one server running SQL Server 2017 with different databases (DB1, DB2, DB3), each one has different use and different tables. I have created a function in DB1 called `DBFTN1`  where it use tables allocated only in DB1.

When I run this function in SSMS over one instance of DB1 the result is 4 seconds, returning around 4K records, for reference the command that I am using is  similar to

```
SELECT * FROM DBFTN1('20220801');
```

When I run the same function using one instance in DB2

```
SELECT * FROM DB1.DBFTN1('20220801');
```

the result is similar around 4 seconds and returns the same records. But when I run the same function from DB3 the performance is very slow, the first records appear in around 25 seconds and it needs around 15 minutes to download the 4k records, the command  used is similar

```
SELECT * FROM DB1.DBFTN1('20220801');
```

What is happening and how can I get similar performance over any  instance?

Is important to mention that the server doesn't have another process running when I run the test.

I have tried run the following sentence over the DB3 instance but the result continue being the same:

```
EXEC sp_updatestats

EXEC sp_msForEachTable @COMMAND1= 'DBCC DBREINDEX ( "?")';

CHECKPOINT 
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS 

DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
```

Thank in advance for your help.

Comment: What do you see when you inspect the execution plan?

Comment: Different databases or different instances? Databases and instances are entirely different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the complete code of your UDF it is difficult to answer such a question...

Please put the complete code and all the execution plan. There is a tool in SSMS to compare two different execution plans.

I suspect that you have some differences of config parameters between your databases. There is two levels of configuration that can modify an execution plan :

- the database parameters
- the scoped database parameters

Just have a look over these values with some queries :

```
SELECT * FROM sys.databases;

SELECT "DB1" AS DBAME, * FROM DB1.sys.database_scoped_configurations
UNION ALL
SELECT "DB2" AS DBAME, * FROM DB1.sys.database_scoped_configurations
UNION ALL
SELECT "DB3" AS DBAME, * FROM DB1.sys.database_scoped_configurations;
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, it was very helpful. When I compared the result the only difference was "Compatibility Level", the first two databases DB1 and DB2 were running in compatibility level 100 (Sql Server 2008) and DB3 is running in compatibility level 120 (Sql Server 2014).  I have changed the DB3 to compatibility level 100 too and now it has the same permormance regarding run my user function. Thank you very much!!

Comment: @SalvadorAguilar That's worrisome. Downgrading the compatibility level is not the answer. What's going on here is that the higher compatibility level is using the newer cardinality estimator, which for some reason seems to be giving a different execution plan. You need to really investigate why you are getting a different plan (most likely poor indexing), rather than blindly applying configurations that you don't understand.